# Deploy PHP to Heroku

Tags: php, html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Since Heroku began Facebook integration awhile ago, I've wanted to deploy a few PHP files without having to use Facebook and just viewing my PHP on Heroku. This link here, [Deploying Wordpress to Heroku](http://tjstein.com/2011/09/running-wordpress-on-heroku-and-amazon-rds/) simply states you can. But, I can't seem to figure out the PHP portion. I have a Rack app already built and tried some implementation that would just view PHP instead of HTML, and that didn't work. All it did is display static text. The same with just having a PHP file on the app in the /public folder, just displays static text. This has to work somehow since the link I shared works you through the process of getting Wordpress on Heroku. If anyone could, tell me how to get a few PHP files running on my Heroku app, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: PHP support on Heroku is now official and you can just past your files like this: https://github.com/delight-im/Heroku-PHP-Apache2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need to do anything - just push your PHP code up and Heroku magic will occur - I'm no PHP guru but recently had to deploy a PHP site and I just pushed the code as is to a new Cedar app, no changing of directory structures etc and it works.

Comment: I don't have Cedar on my existing app, will that be a problem?

Comment: yes, you can only deploy PHP apps to the Heroku Cedar stack, make sure you do `heroku create --stack cedar` when you create the app.

Comment: Okay, it's all setup here http://deep-water-7880.herokuapp.com/. I'm not quite sure how to switch from my current app to this one though.

Comment: have a look at the output of `git remote -v`. Does the 'heroku' origin point at the deep-water-7880 application? If so, just push up your app with a git push heroku master.

Comment: The origin of the repo is coming from my original application.

Comment: Should I do a git remote rm heroku?

Comment: yes, do that then add the new one - git remote add heroku <git repo> - get the git repo from the My Apps page on heroku.com. Then push.

Comment: It worked! Thanks man for your help. Gosh, I always thought Cedar was for Facebook.

Comment: I have one more question though. Some of my PHP requires Mysql, is there a way to get ahold of my data from another server our will I need PostgreSQL? Because I'm getting this error when I have a connection to another server http://deep-water-7880.herokuapp.com/login.php

Comment: you will need to use your own mySQl - either an amazon RDS instance or Xeround (xeround.com) will work fine. Mark your question as answered if you're happy it is.

Comment: Okay, will Amazon RDS provide me with the same Mysql cardinals like host name,username, and password?

Comment: Please note that PHP is not a supported technology on Heroku (but it does work).  If you're after support you need to stick to Ruby, Node.js, Clojure, Java, Python, and Scala.

Comment: Does anyone know how to scale a php application on Heroku? I've posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974103/heroku-how-to-bind-requests-to-scaled-process-in-a-php-application

Comment: Just add an index.php file, and no index.htm and you're good.

Answer (score 40):

You need to create your Heroku app on the new Cedar stack. Cedar stack apps reside on the domain herokuapp.com rather than heroku.com, so you'll know if you've got the right one. Then it's really as simple as pushing your PHP files. To create an app on the Cedar stack, use:

`heroku create`

Or, if you'd like to set a name, (i.e. myname.herokuapp.com) use:

`heroku create myapp`

For the benefit of others who are not as au fait with Git, you will also need to set up, commit and push your Git repository:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git push heroku master
```

That's it! Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Cedar is now the default stack so you can use: `heroku create myapp` without `--stack cedar` now :)

Comment: cedar filesystem is non persistent, so how does heroku handle sessions with multiple dynos running? should i use sessions on the database? because that's what the [12-factor app](http://www.12factor.net/) sugests...

Comment: @hugo_leonardo That sounds like another question you should ask if someone hasn't asked it already.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku now has a guide for deploying PHP, [Getting Started with PHP on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#introduction), which explains that Heroku depends on [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).